# create a table of 900 attributes in mysql

Tags: mysql

Im trying to create a really big sql table that consists of 900 attributes. Is there an easy way to create a table in mysql that consists of 900 attributes without having to manually type them in? I have the name of attributes in a text file

Comment: Sure. Write a quick program in your language of choice to generate the SQL statement for you. Of course, the fact that you want to have 900 columns (does MySQL even support that many?) probably means you have a very broken data model.

Comment: There are good suggestions here how to pull this off. However, 900 fields is terrible practice for MySQL. Either denormalize your table or look into something like MongoDB.

Comment: 900 columns is a terrible practice for ANY database, not just MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get each "attribute" into an array.

Do a foreach loop on the array which builds your query string.

Copy and paste that query string into phpMyAdmin or insert it into the database however you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a scripting language like python to insert using a program. 
To use python you need to install the module MySQLdb

refer this tutorial on how to use python with mysql

http://www.kitebird.com/articles/pydbapi.html